# Build shim requires missing file efi.mk

Tags: debian, uefi, boot-loader

I'm trying to build shim on debian (buster), [sources from git](https://github.com/rhboot/shim).

It's missing the file called `efi.mk` which is necessary from `include/defaults.mk`, [line 81](https://github.com/rhboot/shim/blob/476cbff111001d01a5a27dc2289fc7cd2d34c38e/include/defaults.mk#L81).

The package [gnu-efi 3.0.9-1](https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/gnu-efi/filelist) does not contain such a file, and I couldn't find a package like gnu-efi-devel for debian.

How to build shim for debian?

Answer (score 1):

First call

```
make update
```

In order to initialize `/edk2`.

Then (if not already installed) the package gnu-efi-devel is necessary: check `/usr/include` if the file `efi.mk` is present. I found some recent builds on [this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnu-efi/), your distribution and architecture might be working as well.